# Adding Advanced Custom Field into OnClick JS function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a JS function that replaces text inside a h2 and span.  The JS function is run using OnClick.

This works in all cases, but NOT when I change the value to what is pulled from an Advanced Custom Field in Wordpress.

Whenever the code is changed to `the_field('content');` or `get_field('content');` in a variable, it throws up the **error** `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF`.

The Field is a basic text field, that currently outputs:

```
<p>test8</p>
```

It is being pulled in correctly in the html if I check the source.

The code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function ReplaceHeader(id,content) {
      var container = document.getElementById(id);
      container.innerHTML = content;
      }
</script>

    <?php $artist = get_field('artists_content'); ?>
         <a href="" onclick="ReplaceHeader('header','Artists'); ReplaceHeader('content','<?php echo $artist;?>')">

      <path class="st3" d="M383.5,238.6c3.8,0,6.8-3.1,6.8-6.8s-3.1-6.8-6.8-6.8c-3.8,0-6.8,3.1-6.8,6.8l0,0
      C376.6,235.5,379.7,238.6,383.5,238.6"/>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 398.2288 235.1945)" class="st3 st4 st5">ARTISTS</text>
    </a>
```

This works:

```
<a href="" onclick="ReplaceHeader('header','Artists'); ReplaceHeader('content','<p>Test8</p>')">
```

and even this works:

```
<?php $artist = '<p>Test8</p>' ?>
    <a href="" onclick="ReplaceHeader('header','Artists'); ReplaceHeader('content','<?php echo $artist;?>')">
```

But this doesn't:

```
<?php $artist = get_field('artists_content'); ?>
         <a href="" onclick="ReplaceHeader('header','Artists'); ReplaceHeader('content','<?php echo $artist;?>')">
```

Comment: After a bit more digging, it looks like a WYSIWYG field in Advanced Custom Fields adds an extra space at the end of the value, which then creates a line break in the code.  Anyone know a solution to remove that?

Comment: you could trim it with trim( $value )

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner. $artist = get_field('artists_content'); $artist is a func not a value.